# openmp optimization with return condition

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP parallel programming and finding it difficult to optimize my function, which should return -1 in case a column is empty.

Here is my function.
The source matrix has some values, and `norm_matrix` is constructed as a diagonal matrix where each column holds the maximum value from the corresponding column of the source matrix.

I'm performing this on matrix size of 1000
For example, if my source matrix is

```
 3   2   3   3
 2   4   5   5
 1   4  91   8
32  12   9  63
```

then the computed `norm_matrix` will be

```
32   0   0   0
 0  12   0   0 
 0   0  91   0 
 0   0   0  63
```

If any column contains all zeros then the function should return -1.

Here is my function that I'm trying to optimize in OpenMP:

```
int statistic_norm_matrix(double* source_matrix, double* norm_matrix, int size) {
   int col, row;

   for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
      norm_matrix[col * size + col] = source_matrix[col];

      for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         norm_matrix[col * size + col] = fmax(norm_matrix[col * size + col], source_matrix[row * size + col]);
      }

      if (norm_matrix[col * size + col] == 0) {
         printf("can't process a matrix where the max col value is 0");
         return -1;
      }

      norm_matrix[col * size + col] = (1 / norm_matrix[col * size + col]);

      if (col == size - 1) {
         print_matrix("matrix-norm", norm_matrix, size);
      }
   }
   return 0;
```

This is an attempt at parallelizing with OpenMP, but I see no performance difference:

```
int statistic_norm_matrix(double* source_matrix, double* norm_matrix, int size) {
   int col, row;
    int flag=0;
   
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(source_matrix,norm_matrix) private(col,row) 
        for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            norm_matrix[col * size + col] = source_matrix[col];

                for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                    norm_matrix[col * size + col] = fmax(norm_matrix[col * size + col], source_matrix[row * size + col]);
                }
        
                if (norm_matrix[col * size + col] == 0) {
                    printf("can't process a matrix where the max col value is 0");
                    flag=-1;
                }

                norm_matrix[col * size + col] = (1 / norm_matrix[col * size + col]);

            }

        print_matrix("matrix-norm", norm_matrix, size);
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: Good to know Bosch is an amazing company :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `norm_matrix[col * size + col] == 0` you would get a dividing by zero error on the statement `(1 / norm_matrix[col * size + col]);`. Assuming that when the `flag = -1` you should exit the parallel region completely, you should use #pragma omp cancel for

```
int statistic_norm_matrix(double* source_matrix, double* norm_matrix, int size) {
        int flag = 0;   
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(source_matrix,norm_matrix)
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
             norm_matrix[col * size + col] = source_matrix[col];
             for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                 norm_matrix[col * size + col] = fmax(norm_matrix[col * size + col], source_matrix[row * size + col]);
             }
             if (norm_matrix[col * size + col] == 0) {
                    flag = -1;
                    #pragma omp cancel for
             }

             norm_matrix[col * size + col] = (1 / norm_matrix[col * size + col]);
        }

     print_matrix("matrix-norm", norm_matrix, size);
     return flag;
}
```

I did a quick benchmark on my machine (*i.e.,* with 4 cores) measuring the time of the `statistic_norm_matrix` alone, without counting the `print_matrix`, and for a matrix `1000x1000`:

1 Thread : Time taken is 0.010852 (s)

2 Threads Time taken is 0.005325 (s)

4 Threads Time taken is 0.002891 (s)

for a matrix `10000x10000`:

1 Thread Time taken is 1.937415 (s)

2 Threads Time taken is 1.052908 (s)

4 Threads Time taken is 0.807185 (s)

The tests with 1 thread were done without any `openmp` directives. So either something is wrong with the way of are compiling/running and your code is not actually running in parallel or something is wrong with the way that you are measuring the times.

Comment: Cancellation was introduced as early as in OpenMP 4.0. Older compilers should support it.